Some applications temporarily unresponsive after fresh boot of Ubuntu 24.04
Since I upgraded my system to Ubuntu 24.04 (from 23.10), I’ve been experiencing some peculiar performance issues:
In the first hour or so after booting, some applications tend to freeze suddenly upon some actions.
Ubuntu then shows a dialog like “‘Application XY’ is not responding” with the option to “Force quit” or “Wait”. Usually the action completes after roughly half a minute.
For example:

Firefox (Snap version)

especially on right-click and actions in the context menu (even expanding another menu level; in these cases, an unresponsiveness dialog is shown for the main window as well as each open context menu level)
sometimes even input like scrolling using the mouse wheel or text input in a form field


Gnome Terminal

especially opening a new tab or switching between tabs
sometimes even text input



Other applications seem to be completely unaffected, I did never observe this problem for any Flatpak applications for example.
All this happens despite very low system load (CPU, memory, IO). Interestingly, after an hour or so, everything works fluently again.
My suspicion is that there is some problem with a GTK component, but I have no idea how to examine this. Any suggestions?

Any findings on this? I'm experiencing similar issues where applications freeze--the right click on terminal regularly reproduces the issue. Nothing relevant bubbling up to logs. I also lost sound and WIFI stability after the upgrade, but I was able to restore WIFI by defining DNS in multiple places.

@Scorpius Not really, unfortunately, as it is very hard to reproduce. Have you got the same situation, i.e. all problems gone after some uptime (about an hour or longer)?
At least in this seemingly stable state, a right click on Gnome Terminal works normally, so we might have different problems.

@Scorpius However, I’ve made some observations in the meantime, suggesting
that the UX is better on X11 than on Wayland (e.g. the “sometimes” observations from my post only apply to Wayland, I’ve never seen them on X11),
and that the problem might be sound related, as applications often freeze when sound is played (only tested on X11). Interestingly, this was only the case when using sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl as audio driver which was the default on my system. Yesterday I tried using snd_hda_intel by setting snd_intel_dspcfg.dsp_driver=1 which led to much better performance.

My current suspicion is therefore that the problems could be specific to some hardware/firmware/drivers. My system involves an Intel Tiger Lake CPU (with Xe graphics) plus a GeForce GPU. The free nouveau driver really did not work (flickering, artifacts, ...), and I did not observe any differences between using the proprietary nvidia-driver-{470,535,550}. (No evidence or solution found yet.)

I also have this issue with Firefox and also Gnome Terminal. So I filed a bug and it is now accepted. See here: Bug 2081281
There you can see, that I tested it with gtk3-demo and gtk4-demo as well and I could see, that apps that are using QT and not gtk are not affected. You can test on your site and report in the bug history. Also at the top of the bug page you can click to say, that this bugs affects you as well. So the bug has more votes and might be fixed earlier.

Launchpad [Bug 2081281: gnome terminal and other apps freezes for about 30 seconds

I have the same issue. I've been trying to capture an strace during the freeze, but was unsuccessful so far. I'll try again tomorrow, I'm pretty sure the applications are blocking on some fd operations, seeing which fd is the culprit may implicate a specific subsystem.

(I realize this might be a long shot, and most likely not the issue you're having.)
I upgraded to Ubuntu 24.04.1 and also started to having weird and random performance issues. It appears that somehow the "Screen reader" feature had been turned on. I did not realize this as I did not have speakers on the computer. After plugging in headphones, I noticed that it was the problem. Turning off the screen reader feature fixed the issue for me.

I have tracked this problem down to pipewire, which replaced pulseaudio in Ubuntu 24.04 as the default audio mixing and output system.
A quick fix that gets rids of some of the hangs is to disable system sounds in Gnome settings. After that, Gnome terminal was usable again on my system, but Firefox still had issues.
Reverting my system back to pulseaudio fixed all hangs for me. To do that, first, disable pipewire with
sudo systemctl --global mask status pipewire.socket
sudo systemctl --global mask status pipewire

(use --user instead of --global and drop the sudo if you only want this to take effect for the current user). Then, make sure pulseaudio is installed (it was already in my system, but that may be because I upgraded from 22.04)
sudo apt install pulseaudio pulseaudio-utils

Finally, enable pipewire. I'm not exactly sure anymore what state it was in after the upgrade to 24.04, but the following should do the trick
sudo systemctl --global unmask status pulseaudio.socket
sudo systemctl --global enable status pulseaudio.socket
sudo systemctl --global unmask status pulseaudio
sudo systemctl --global enable status pulseaudio

(use --user instead of --global and drop the sudo if you only want this to take effect for the current user). Now after logging out and back in (or manuall stopping pipewire and starting pulseaudio using systemctl) you should be using pulseaudio.
